# How to add same Dependencies to two different War - Gradle

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle, war, gradle-plugin

I am working on Project where we are creating different artifacts with Jar and wars. I have situatuon where I need to create separate War file as mentioned in the code with name "email" task.
I would like to add external dependencies in that war . How can i do it.
There are many external dependencies but to make it short I have removed all.

```
    plugins {
    id 'prj1.build'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'prj1.artifactory.dm' version '3.02.05.001'
  
}
  
subprojects { p ->
   apply plugin: 'prj1.build'
   apply plugin: 'java-library'
}

allprojects { p -> prj1ArtifactoryDM { gradleConstraintsDM(prj:p) {} } }

    prj1Build {

    xsds( jaxb:'2.3.1' ) {
        genXsd {
           from 'config/WEB-INF/services/bulkdocuments/BulkDocGenRequest-V1.0.xsd'
           params package: 'java.test.prj1.nps.bulkdocgenrequest_v1'
        }
        task genXsdCoiDocGenRequest(type: java.test.prj1.cicd.xsd.GenXsdTask) {
            from 'config/WEB-INF/services/coidocuments/CoiDocGenrequest-V1.0.xsd'
            params package:'java.test.prj1.nps.coidocuments_v1'
            compileCodegenJava.dependsOn genXsdCoiDocGenRequest
        }
            
    }
 
    jars {   
        apiJar()
    }
      wars {
         // Require all dependencies in this war from this project I tried to copy it didnt work.
        task email(type: War) {
            rootSpec.include("**/domain/**",  
                "**java/test/prj1/nps/common/service/npsHiprj1rchService/**",
                "**java/test/prj1/nps/common/exception/**",
                "**java/test/prj1/nps/common/util/**",
                
            )
            rootSpec.rename ('applicationContext-nps-jobs.xml','applicationContext.xml')
            extension = 'job'
        }
    }
  
    publish ( devStage: { artifacts = [apiJar, war,email] } ){
    
    }
    
 
}

ext {
    version = '2.05.00.008'
  }

dependencies {
    api ("prj1.imp:imp:${version}") {
    }
    compileOnly "prj1.imp:imp-compile:${version}"
    testImplementation "prj1.imp:imp-compile:${version}"
    
    }

}
```

I need to copy all Jar files from project to task email Type war. I tried creating task and copy to web-inf/lib folder but couldnt do that.
Could you please Guide me correct way to do.

Thank you